Can we infer the type of the last parameter of a callback argument from a previous argument?
I'm trying to write a little helper function that acts like a decorator which purpose is to avoid the redundant pattern of doing:
function someFunction(..., options?: Partial<SomeOptionsType>) {
  const optionsWithDefaults: SomeOptionsType = {
    ...someDefaultOptions,
    ...(options ?? {}),
  }
}

when a function takes an options object as its last argument, so I wrote this code:
export type WithDefaultOptions<
  Options extends object,
  Callback extends (...args: [...any[], Options]) => any,
> = Callback extends (...args: [...infer Args, Options]) => infer Ret
  ? (...args: [...Args, Partial<Options>?]) => Ret
  : never;

export function withDefaultOptions<
  Options extends object,
  Callback extends (...args: [...any[], Options]) => any,
>(
  defaults: Options,
  callback: Callback,
): WithDefaultOptions<Options, Callback> {
  return ((...args) =>
    callback(
      ...[
        ...args.slice(0, -1),
        {
          ...defaults,
          ...(args[args.length - 1] ?? {}),
        },
      ],
    )) as WithDefaultOptions<Options, Callback>;
}

But the problem I'm facing is that I want to be able to call the function without passing it any generic parameter, and get the Options type from the defaults arguments, until here everything works fine, but I want to be able to infer the type of the last parameter of the second callback argument without having to type it explicitely, but I want to still have to type explicitely the first parameters, but I can't manage to get it working, for example:
const split = withDefaultOptions(
  {
    max: 0,
  },
  (s: string, options) => {
    // Here I want `options` to get the type of `defaults` (`{ max: number }`) inferred, 
    // but I get any, and a TypeError if not typing it explicitely
  },
);


you can't have any parameters after rest syntax, please provide a valid example at https://www.typescriptlang.org/

with types you can I think because the type WithDefaultOptions works correctly and sets the last parameter to optional and partial

check someFunction()

@AlexanderNenashev I edited the snipped, its purpose is not being functional, it's showing what the goal of my function is (that the callback can take an arbitrary number of arguments before the options), someFunction doesnt matter for this problem, the other snippets on the other hand are valid typescript

"Its purpose is not being functional". Okay, but for this to be a [mre] the implementation should work, if provided; right now you're doing something very weird: e.g., if you call split("xyz") then you're calling the callback with something like {0: "x", 1: "y", 2: "z", max: 0} which is just... bonkers. See this playground link. If you don't care about functionality, you can use declare instead of providing an incorrect implementation, like in this playground link. Please [edit] so we're not distracted by this.

(pls see prev comment and make requested edit) This fights against TS but I think I have as close to a solution as possible. See this playground link. It ends up assuming all unannotated parameters are the same as the type of defaults. So a trailing unannotated parameter will be inferred as the expected type. But so will any other unannotated parameter. Maybe that's not an issue, I hope? Also if your last parameter is annotated incorrectly it should error. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?

"I want to be able to call the function without passing it any generic parameter, and get the Options type from the defaults arguments" - I would recommend the inverse, to have it infer the type from the Callback type parameter (and remove Options as a type parameter altogether). Then write withDefaultOptions(…, (s: string, options: SomeOptionsType) => { … }).
